# serializable string in hibernate save(Object entity, Serializable id)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, typing

I want to persist using a specific id-
String tdsSubmissionId; Myclass myclass;
this.hibernateTemplate.save(myclass, tdsSubmissionId);

using this signature- save(Object entity, Serializable id)

but I get the error-
the method save(String, Object)  is not applicable for the arguments (Myclass, String)

Seems like it's being autotyped incorrectly. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such method as `save(entity, id)`, and that's what the error is telling you.

Your entity must already have the ID set, and you can pass it to `hibernateTemplate.save(entity)`.

Comment: I just want to load my table with a specified id and not let hibernate create the id. so if found this method in hibernatetemplate- save(Object entity, Serializable id). How else can I do it? Thanks

Comment: as I said - set the ID in the entity before calling save

Comment: As told by Bozho you can set the ID before calling save or you can mention the type of generation for the primary key in the hibernate xml or through annotations. The @GeneratedValue annotation has options to specify whether the id should be auto generated or through a sequence or through a custome generation class.

Comment: Thanks. But any reason what's wrong with the method that I was trying to use?

Comment: It does not exist. I checked HibernateTemplate and it does not have such a method

Comment: If I set the id first, I get a 'detached entity passed to persist' error. Any ideas on possible workarounds? Thanks

Comment: do you have a record with the same ID in the database?

Comment: no, i'm creating a new record. I tried persist, save, saveOrUpdate, merge.. but none of them works. save is the only one which didn't throw an error, but it adds that record with +1 of max(id) of that entity instead of the id that i specified. Thanks.

Comment: If you have an auto-increment id, you can't set a value.